# Is there an iOS equivalent to the Android API method getAllCellInfo?

Tags: ios, swift, cell, cellular-network

Android has an API method: [getAllCellInfo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getAllCellInfo()) that "returns all observed cell information from all radios on the device including the primary and neighboring cells". On iOS, I've found the [CTCarrier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/ctcarrier) class to obtain information about the current user's home cellular service provider. I'm attempting to get all available external cell tower information from an iOS device.

Does iOS have a getAllCellInfo() equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIDevice.current
```

Returns an object representing the current device.

You could maybe extend from `UIDevice` create your own method and return the stuff that you need, have a look at all the props here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice

Comment: Thank you for your response, however I'm looking to find external cell tower information, not just information about the current device. Maybe I need to reword my question a bit

Comment: External info as? Company name? or what else?

Comment: Android has API's to get cell identity information. For example, a GSM cell identity has these properties: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentityGsm, which actually gets information about the cell tower in range.